# Get all models related to this model in django (via ForeignKey, ManyToMany)

Tags: python, django, django-models, related-content

I have to get all the models related to my current model. The relations can be by ForeignKey, ManyToManyField or OneToONeField, from this model or to this model.

For eg:

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
 field = models.Charfield(...)
 type = models.ForeignKey('Type', ...)

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
 label = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, ...)
 ...

class Type(models.Model):
 name = models...
 ...
```

I need to find related models of the model `MyModel`, that means if I have a function `get_related_models`,
`get_related_models(MyModel)` should return `[AnotherModel,Type]`

Note:The ultimate use of this is I need to invalidate cache of `MyModel` when ever there is any change in this model and its related models(By using some `post_save`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with the `_meta` options.

```
[rel.model for rel in MyModel._meta.get_all_related_objects()]
```

Comment: It will return [AnotherModel], but not [AnotherModel, Type]. But its ok because we can find foreignkey models in another way by selecting all fields with foreign key and its model.                         for field in ModelC._meta.fields:
    if field.get_internal_type() == "ForeignKey":
        print field.rel.to